# Moving tomato seedlings outside right after germinating?

Tags: vegetables, tomatoes

I'm trying to grow tomato from seed. I know it's a bit late. Daytime temps here are consistently 60-70F right now. I know that's not optimal for germination, but it's good for growth of tomatoes.

My question is, can I germinate inside, but then as soon as germination occurs, move the seedlings outside to get full sun and environmental conditions? My rationale is that in this way, I can avoid the process of hardening the plants. The daytime temps seem fine for the tomatoes. Night sometimes drops high 40's, low 50's, but i can move the containers inside if need be during the night.

Is this OK? Will moving the seedlings outside immediately kill them, or will this (as I am assuming) make them hardy and strong from the get-go since they don't grow indoors?

Answer (score 1):

You should not move them straight outside when they are small seedlings - the sun will kill them,and they won't like the fluctuating  temperatures (even during the day) so those conditions will check their growth anyway. Much better to prick them out into pots after they start growing and grow them on a bit, then harden them off when they're reasonably sized plants so they're ready to go  outdoors all the time.